# How do I use UI Automation Library to calculate load time for UIElement/FrameworkElement on button click?

Tags: .net, wpf, ui-automation, uielement, frameworkelement

My application has a button which creates a `UIElement`/`FrameworkElement` on the fly.

I want to use the UI Automation library to click on the button so the element shows up.  My problem I want to calculate the time it takes for the `UIElement`/`FrameworkElement` to show up or get created.

Is this possible using the UI Automation Library provided by Microsoft and how do I achieve this?

I know using Coded UI Tests I can use WaitForControlReady() but is there a way to do this using UI Automation Library?  The Coded UI tests don't work for all custom controls.